# Reference request for spectral theory of elliptic operators

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, differential-operators

I want to learn the spectral theory of linear elliptic operators in bounded and unbounded domains in $R^n$, in particular for Laplacian and Schrodinger operators. Please suggest me some reference.
I have studied second order Elliptic pde from Evans Chapter 6. There he discusses spectrum for case of bounded domain. I want to study how spectrum behaves in case of unbounded domain also. I want to explore functional analytic viewpoint of Elliptic Operators.

Comment: The question is to vast. You need to be more specific.

Comment: Hoermander's books are a good point to start. However, it depends very much on what you have in mind. From my perspective, I can say that the theory of heat kernels, as in Berline,Getzler,Vergne and Shubin's book were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics
With Applications to Schrödinger Operators
Gerald Teschl